# Simple Java Http Server with Support for Bytes-Range

Tags: java, http, range, http-live-streaming

I need a simple HTTP server library for Java which handles range requests correctly and let me decide which data is uploaded. I need a library which I can hand over something like that:

```
public InputStream getInputStreamForRangeRequest(String resource, long fromBytes, long toBytes) 
{
    return new MyLimitedStream(resource, fromBytes, toBytes);
}
```

Why do I need this ? I'm working on a video streaming platform where the video data do not come from the file-system but is stored in memory instead. So the video has to be read from memory instead of the fs.

Is there library out there helping me with this sort of task ?

Comment: Why the downvotes ? It's a clear question... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

http://pygmy-httpd.sourceforge.net/

Range requests are supported.